# A Full-Width Centered Navigation Top Bar - Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am using **Zurb Foundation 4** and I need my top bar navigation to be centered as **.large-12.columns**

[image]

I tried the following (but it doesn't work)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
      <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
          ...
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
          <ul class="left">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpaluy/rDus6/) based on [Foundation Example](http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/workspace.html)
  If the browser size is big, the navigation width changes. But I want it to be centered fixed as main content.

Comment: please create a fiddle to make it simple for understand

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As the Foundation 4 docs saying :
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

> If you want your navigation to be set to your grid width, wrap it in
>   **div class="contain-to-grid"**.

So try using the following :

```html
<div class="contain-to-grid">
    <!-- Your nav bar -->
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title area here... -->
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
                <!-- Title area here... -->
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
                <!-- Title area here... -->
            </ul>
        </section>
     </nav>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: This works, and that Foundation doc page should contain this info, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly what you want, you just need to wrap your **nav.top-bar** element in a **div** with class **contain-to-grid**.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="contain-to-grid">
    <nav class="top-bar">
      <ul class="title-area">
        ...
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="left">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>

    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. It seems like exactly what I was trying to do do to get the bar working but I couln't until I copied and pasted this code.  This worked.

Answer (score 1):

The foundation framework allows nested `row`the first `<div class="row">` get the width of the page but you can put another `<div class="row">`into it which is going a smaller 12-columns-max-width.

You can check the docs related to this feature here : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Are you sure the row you paste in the question is the first one in your HTML code ? If it is, can you paste a link for a demo of your code please?

### EDIT

If i understand it rights, it pretty simple to do with CSS :

```
.top-bar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="contain-to-grid">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <ul class="menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion">
                <li><a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```