# Full width search top bar for small in Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, stylesheet, zurb-foundation

I am doing top bar similar to this:

http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/workspace.html

Only requirement is on smaller device, I like to hide everything and only show search bar in full width. I got the "hiding" worked by using `.hide-for-small` for `.title-area a` and others but I cannot figure out the **proper way** to make that search bar goes **full width in small size**. I **DO NOT** want to hack.

I tried to put `.row` and `.small-12 .large-12 .columns` under `.top-bar-section` but that just screwed it up more. I believe row/column isn't supposed to be used in `top-bar`?

Here is the desired outcome:

[image]

What are my options? Do I customize my own `top-bar`? Or is there some class to force full width of `top-bar-section`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to wrap your `top-bar` in a div class `contain-to-grid`?

[A Full-Width Centered Navigation Top Bar - Zurb Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712294/a-full-width-centered-navigation-top-bar-zurb-foundation)