# Can't get a Full-Width Centered Navigation Top Bar in Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

This question was answered here:

[A Full-Width Centered Navigation Top Bar - Zurb Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712294/a-full-width-centered-navigation-top-bar-zurb-foundation)

And I tried that solution and it doesn't seem to work -- I only see my left items on the left, and my right items on the right. I would like them to be centered within the row.

What I have is:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="contain-to-grid">
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <!--none-->
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="left">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made a jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SxTty/

You need to make the result bigger to see the menu. The full-screen result is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/SxTty/embedded/result/

Comment: Are you trying to make the links appear within the confines of the 1000px grid area? Or are you trying to have the black background "stretch" 100% across the window?

Comment: I would just like to appear within the 1000px window, and have the menu links be centered within that (i.e. without that large space between the left and the right).

Answer (score 0):

Well I got something working "good enough" but I certainly don't like it.

I took out the moved the items from 'right' to the 'left' and remove the 'right' list

```
  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```

And then added a margin to the first li:

```
 .top-bar  li:first-child {

     margin-left: 150px;
 }
```

That works -- I can move the left margin over. But this solution seems too hacky for me.

Here is the latest jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/squarepegsys/QKpBW/5/

I'm more than willing to entertain something better.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `left` class and making the list an inline-block (which you can then center):

```
.top-bar-section {
    text-align: center;
}
.top-bar-section ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UmMY9/1/

Answer (score -1):

Apply these Styles:

```
.top-bar ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top:20px;
}


.top-bar {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Sami. I updated the jsFiddle but your sugguestion gives the same result to what I have.